# BizTalk 2016 Singleton

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We have a flow that processes incoming bank statements from an external system to SAP. The process itself is rather simple

1. Receive bank statement via SFTP
2. Send to SAP via FTP
3. Call SAP RFC with filename as parameter

This all happens in an orchestration and on BizTalk side it's working fine.
Now, they have noticed that SAP has some issues when too many bank statements arrive at the same time. So we need to redesign the orchestration so it handles them 1-by-1.

So, my first thought was to redesign it as a Singleton orchestration to solve this issue. Does anybody have some other suggestions to fix this issue?
The messages don't need to be processed in a specific order. Just slower. :-)

I'm just a bit afraid of the possible sideffects of a Singleton.

Comment: how about save context to database table and retrieve 1x1 using wcf polling?

Comment: Quickest fix would be to set the send port to ordered delivery. That will force BizTalk to send one at a time

Comment: @Dijkgraaf That's indeed a pattern we use sometimes. Didn't really think about that one for this problem. Thanks for the hint. I enabled the checkbox on the sendport that calls the RFC in SAP. Let's see if it's enough. :-)

Comment: You should talk to the SAP boys to optimize their RFC... Or just get rid of the entire RFC call, because you already delivered the message on their ftp server right? Let them deal with it...

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting the port on a dedicated host and configure resource based throttling.

If that doesn't suit, consider a Resource Dispenser pattern which is described here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23924.biztalk-server-resource-dispenser-send-port-edition.aspx

Basically, messages are queued for a limited number of receiving service instances, and  the destination send ports are set to ordered delivery, so each will have only on active instance.